# How to prevent multiple connections with socket.io on page redirect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, redirect, socket.io

I am building a NodeJS app with Express and Socket.IO that instructs the client side script to redirect the user to a different page based on certain conditions.  The problem that I am having is that when it redirects, I get another socket connection.  In my code I keep track of socket sessions based on the socket ID in order to send messages to specific sockets to perform actions on them. Since the redirect creates a new socket with a new ID, I am no longer able to achieve this functionality.

I've tried disconnecting a socket before redirecting, sending a message after connecting to disconnect the previous socket, etc.  Nothing seems to work to allow me to easily manage a single socket connection with redirects.

**Disclaimer: I'm totally new to Node, Socket.io, etc.**

Here is my server code:

```
var http    = require('http'),
    express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = http.createServer(app);
var io      = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = 8000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var activeClientId;
var clientQ = [];
var clients = {};
var numUsers = 0;

function updateActive() {
    console.log("Updating active client...");

    activeClientId = clientQ.shift();
    var active = clients[activeClientId];
    while (!checkActive() && clientQ.length > 0) {
        if (typeof active !== 'undefined' && active !== null) {
            delete clients[activeClientId];
            active.disconnect();
            console.log("Force Disconnect Client: " + activeClientId);
            numUsers = Object.keys(clients).length;
        }

        activeClientId = clientQ.shift();
        active = clients[activeClientId];
    }

    if (checkActive()) {
        console.log("New Active Client: " + activeClientId);
    } else {
        console.log("Active Client Not Updated");
    }
};

function checkActive() {
    var active = clients[activeClientId];
    return typeof active !== 'undefined' && active !== null && active.connected;
};

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    clients[socket.id] = socket;
    clientQ.push(socket.id);

    numUsers = Object.keys(clients).length;

    console.log("Client " + "#" + numUsers + " connected: " + socket.id);

    if (numUsers === 1) {
        activeClientId = socket.id;
    } else {
        updateActive();
    }

    if (socket.id === activeClientId) {
        socket.emit('game');
    } else {
        socket.emit('wait');
    }

    socket.on('play', function () {
        console.log("users: " + numUsers);
        console.log("curId: " + socket.id);
        console.log("actId: " + activeClientId);

        if (socket.id !== activeClientId && numUsers > 1) {
            socket.emit('kick');
        } else {
            console.log("Game started on client: " + socket.id);
        }
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log("Client " + "#" + numUsers + " disconnected: " + socket.id);

        delete clients[socket.id];

        numUsers = Object.keys(clients).length;

        updateActive();

        socket.broadcast.emit('disconnected', {
            numUsers: numUsers
        });
    });
});

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port: %d', port);
});
```

And my client:

```
$(function () {
    var socket = io();

    socket.on('game', function (data) {
        socket.disconnect();
        window.location.replace("/game");
    });

    socket.on('wait', function (data) {
        socket.disconnect();
        window.location.replace("/wait");
    });
});
```

The code for the `/game` page:

```
$(function () {
    var socket = io();

    socket.on('connect', function (data) {
        socket.emit('play');
    });

    socket.on('kick', function(data) {
        socket.disconnect();
        alert("KICK!");
        window.location.replace("/wait");
    });
});
```

The code for the `\wait` page:

```
$(function () {
    var socket = io();

    socket.on('connect', function (data) {
        socket.emit('wait');
    });

    socket.on('game', function (data) {
        socket.disconnect();
        window.location.replace("/game");
    });
});
```

Comment: Every new web page will be a new socket connection because you can't preserve a connection across pages, so if you're redirecting to a new page, you will lose the prior socket connection.  You can cookie the browser with an id and when it reconnects after redirect, use that id.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. But when I redirect, shouldn't that trigger a `disconnect` for socket.io if the connection is not preserved?  It isn't currently, and this is causing my array of connected sessions to just keep growing on each redirect.

Comment: There should be a disconnect event on the server if you're listening for the right event.

Comment: I'm using `socket.on('disconnect')` on the server, and logging a message to console in its callback.  I don't see any disconnect when I redirect to another page, only when I manually close the tab.

Comment: I do see issues in the client where you're trying to `.emit()` on the socket immediately after connecting without waiting for the connected event (which means you don't wait for socket.io to do it's initial handshake).  That could be complicating things as you may be getting an error there which results in the socket getting closed right away.

Comment: You mean where I do `socket.emit('connected')`? What would be the correct way to begin communications between the server and client once a successful connection is established then? I am currently doing this via that call in the client and the `socket.on('connected')` listener in the server.

Comment: You have to wait for the connected event on the client BEFORE you emit anything on the client end (which you are not doing in the client code in your question).  Plenty of client examples here: http://socket.io/docs/

Comment: Ah, alright.  I've update all of the code on the OP.  Still not quite there, but is this more in line with what you were talking about?

Comment: You shouldn't be emitting a `connected` message from your server because that message is already used by the protocol and should mean something different in the client.  Pick a different name for your own message.

Comment: I updated the OP code again.  I fixed what you suggested and added some code to manually disconnect sockets when redirecting since they weren't doing it on their own.  It still isn't quite fixing the issue, and I still have several extra sockets. Any other input on what I have?

Comment: An abrupt disconnect may take a short while for the server to notice the lack of keep-alives.  Are you waiting long enough?

Comment: How long should I have to wait?  And where should I have it waiting before performing an action?

Comment: If you're keeping a constant ID value per browser, you could also just remove existing sockets with the same ID on the server whenever a new connection arrives and let that be part of your cleanup.  The way keep-alives work, the server will notice after some period of time that it isn't getting keep-alives from the client and drop the socket.  That's how the server prevents orphaned sockets.

Comment: Alright, well at the moment I'm just keeping track of sockets by socket ID.  What value could I retrieve that would be unique to an individual browser?

Comment: I explained earlier that you could coin a unique ID in a cookie for each connecting browser and that cookie value would then be constant.

Answer (score -3):

In client side add some option in IO()

> {transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false}

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:8000',{transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false});
```